# Set max int value in Symfony routing

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, router

Consider the following Symfony2 routing snippet (yml):

```
date:
    pattern:  /{day}-{dutchMonthName}
    defaults: { _controller: bundle }
    requirements:
       day: \d+
       dutchMonthName: januari|februari|maart|april|mei|juni|juli|augustus|september|oktober|november|december
```

As we all know a month is always start by day 1 end (on the max) it will be ended on 31. So i want the day parameter limited from 1 to 31 so it will matches so exact as possible.

**BONUS**
Every month has a other number of days. I know how i can check it in my controller, but is it possible to do this in the router file? So i.e. 'february' the route '30-february' will never exists. Leapyears are not intresting (not on the router) so that will be done in the controller.

Comment: the requirements option accepts RegEx. so with [1-31] you could validate against a range.

Comment: To address bonus, you can always write a condition. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#completely-customized-route-matching-with-conditions

Comment: hmmmm nice! i will try that ;) tnx!